# Segmentation fault when attempting to pass variables to constructor C++

Tags: c++, oop, segmentation-fault

I've been attempting to try and switch over to C++ because I switched universities and am trying to experiment with C++ before my courses start. I run into trouble with the differences with classes in java and c++. I keep getting segmentation faults when I try to call the constructor using input variables as arguments.

```
    static Course createCourse() //attempt to make a static method that fails as well
{ 
    std::string courseCode;
    std::string courseTitle;
    double creditHrs;
    int numOfStudents;
    std::cout<< "Please enter the course code: \n";
    std::getline(std::cin, courseCode);
    std::cout<<"Please enter the course title: \n";
    std::getline(std::cin, courseTitle);
    std::cout << "Please enter the number of credit hours: \n";
    std::cin >> creditHrs;
    std::cout << "Please enter the number of students in the course: \n";
    std::cin >> numOfStudents;
    Course aye(courseCode, courseTitle, creditHrs, numOfStudents); //seg fault
    return aye;
 }

int main()
{
    std::string courseCode;
    std::string courseTitle;
    double creditHrs;
    int numOfStudents;
    std::cout<< "Please enter the course code: \n";
    std::getline(std::cin, courseCode);
    std::cout<<"Please enter the course title: \n";
    std::getline(std::cin, courseTitle);
    std::cout << "Please enter the number of credit hours: \n";
    std::cin >> creditHrs;
    std::cout << "Please enter the number of students in the course: \n";
    std::cin >> numOfStudents;
    std::cout << courseCode << " " << courseTitle << " " << creditHrs << " " << numOfStudents; //just for testing
    Course *newCourse = new Course(courseCode, courseTitle, creditHrs, numOfStudents); //where segmentation fault occurs
    double max = newCourse->getMax();
    double average = newCourse->getAverage();
    double min = newCourse->getMin();
    cout << "The average of the scores is " << average << "\n";
    cout << "The max score is " << max << "\n";
    cout << "The minimum score is " << min << "\n";
}
```

Here is my code for the Course class. I really don't know where this error is occurring. All the course methods function as expected when I directly pass the arguments to the constructor.

```
{
private:
  string courseCode;
  string courseTitle;
  double creditHours;
  vector<double> studentScores;
  int numOfStudents;
  double getSum();

public:
  Course();
  Course(string newCourseCode, string newCourseTitle, double newCreditHrs, int numOfStudents);
  void displayScores();
  void readScores();
  double getAverage();
  double getMax();
  double getMin();
};

//some of my function definitions on separate file
  Course::Course()
  {
      this->courseCode = "nothing";
      this->courseTitle = "empty";
      this->creditHours = 0.0;
      this-> numOfStudents = 0;
  }
  Course::Course(std::string newCourseCode, std::string newCourseTitle, double newCreditHours, int newNumOfStudents){
      this->courseCode = newCourseCode;
      this->courseTitle = newCourseTitle;
      this->creditHours = newCreditHours;
      this->numOfStudents = newNumOfStudents;
  }

  void Course::readScores()
  {
    double score;
    std::cout<< "Enter the scores for " << this->numOfStudents<< " students: \n";
    for(int i = 0; i < this->numOfStudents; i++)
    {
        this->studentScores.push_back(1);
        std::cin >> score;
        this->studentScores[i] = score;
    }
  }

  double Course::getSum()
  {
    double sum = 0;
    double nextNumber;
    for(int i = 0; i < studentScores.size(); i++)
    {
      nextNumber = this->studentScores[i];
      sum += nextNumber;
    }
    return sum;
  }

  double Course::getAverage()
  { double sum = getSum();
    double average = (sum / this->numOfStudents);
    return average;
  }
```

Comment: You're not showing your `Course` class. The code here shouldn't cause a segfault.

Comment: @PMF second file top. I’m not sure you read the question

Comment: @AlexPetrosyan This was added only after my comment.

Comment: This is not a [mre].  Includes are missing, as are function definitions and other things.  This prevents anyone else from reproducing your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You call `getAverage` on courses with zero students. You either need to make `getAverage` handle this case sanely or you need to never call `getAverage` for a course with no students.

Here's a tip: You need to document the requirements of your functions. If it was documented that it was illegal to call `getAverage` with zero students, this problem would have been much easier to detect.

Here's another tip: Add an `assert` or `throw` for cases like this rather than just dividing by zero.